# How to combine two PHP variable names to call one?

Tags: php

I have multiple variables:

```
$Variable1 = '5/5/15';
$Variable2 = '6/13/76';
$Variable3 = '5/8/15';
```

...

I have an iteration variable:

```
$Iteration1 = 1;

while($Iteration1<=3){

    echo "$Variable" . $Iteration1;

    $Iteration1++;
}
```

desired result:

```
5/5/15
6/13/76
5/8/15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The Problem

Your current code `echo "$Variable" . $Iteration1;` tries to echo the value of the variable `$Variable`, which doesn't exist, and concatenate `$Iteration1`.

## The Solution

What you *want* to do is build a string, `"Variable" . $Iteration1` (e.g., `$Variable2`), then get the value of the variable with that name. This is called a "variable variable." You do this by writing `${string_you_want_to_create}`, as in `${"Variable" . $Iteration1}`.

## Example Code For your Problem:

```
$Variable1 = '5/5/15';
$Variable2 = '6/13/76';
$Variable3 = '5/8/15';

$Iteration1 = 1;

while ($Iteration1 <= 3) {

    echo ${"Variable" . $Iteration1} . "\n";

    $Iteration1++;
}
```

*Output:*

```
5/5/15
6/13/76
5/8/15
```

Note: You could also do this in two steps, like this:

```
$variableName = "Variable" . $Iteration1;
echo $$variableName; // note the double $$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
echo ${"Variable" . $Iteration1};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in loop

```
$var = 'Variable'.$Iteration1;
echo $$var.'<br>';
```